# Animation effect in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, animation, demoscene

Can someone point me to a C# open source implementaion with a simple image animations.

e.g. I feed the input image to animator, and the animation code produces a few dozen of images which if displayed sequentially looks like animation.

I am not something extremely fancy - a simple DirectX filter like animations would do.

Comment: I personally don't know of any, but you might want to search for tweening and blending

Answer (score 1):

You would be look for a sprite then?  Microsoft has tutorials on this including:

http://msevents.microsoft.com/cui/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032273446&CountryCode=US

and general graphics in C# here:

http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/msdnvisualcsharp.aspx?tab=webcasts

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I've have created a library called Transitions that lets you animate most properties of UI controls easily. You could use it to move the position of pictures, transition between pictures or grow and shrink pictures. But I'm not sure that this is exactly the effects you're after? Anyway, if it's any help, my library is here:
http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/

Comment: Interesting... I'm gonna check it out :) Thanks for sharing! :)